# sandbox fail to access local socket

Tags: xcode, macos, sockets, sandbox

i've created a local socket in my app, and i'm getting the following error when trying to send data to target process :

deny network-outbound

i've made some research and found out that in order to fix this problem on Xcode based application, i need to to set "Allow Outgoing Network Connections" checkbox in the Summary tab of the target editor.

however, i'm using Xcode 6.3.2 and i don't see such option (summery tab is also missing).

where can i get the equivalent of this checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Xcode 6.4, but it was the same in 6.3.2:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, this is actually what i've needed. however, i also face with additional problem where the socket code is actually wrapped inside a dylib target that injected to existing application during runtime. if this application reject outgoing connection, do i have any way to bypass it in my library ?

Comment: @Zohar Not to my knowledge.  The `.dylib` will be under the same restrictions as the process that loaded it, otherwise it would be easy to circumvent the sandbox.  However I cannot say I've ever tried it.